# Ошибка при подключении к базе SQLite в Java

Tags: java, sqlite, sqlite3

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе SQLite, ввод данных происходит, а запись нет, выскакивает "null"

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program
{
public static void main(String ... args){

    Program program = new Program();
    program.open();
    program.insert();
    program.close();
}

Connection co;
    void open(){
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        co = DriverManager.getConnection (
            "jdbc:sqlite:users.db");
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
void insert(){
    try{

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter user name: ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter user phone: ");
    String phone = scanner.nextLine();

    String query = 
    "INSERT INTO users (name, phone) " +
    "VALUES ('"+ name + "', '" + phone + "')";

    Statement statement = co.createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate (query);
    System.out.println("Rows added");
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}
}

void close(){

try{
    co.close();
}

catch (Exception e){

    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}


}


}
```

Вывод в консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все что находится в директории
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас же должно вывести на экран Connected при успешном подключении. А на скриншоте этого нет.

Comment: Да, но к сожалению что-то не так

Comment: У вас неудачное подключение к БД.

Comment: Я не понимаю почему, вроде все должно быть правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте указать полный путь к БД например: jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/db/chinook.db

И проверьте наличие jdbc драйвера, см. здесь https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/

Смотрите видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnWYNIMTRHY c 9 минуты. Там как раз решение вашей проблемы

Comment: Изменил строку 
co = DriverManager.getConnection (
    "jdbc:sqlite: C:/Database/users.db");
Все равно тот же эффект

Comment: Там пробел в строке подключения не нужен, и проверьте наличие драйвера

Comment: Драйвер имеется, и скриншот директории добавил, та есть все и библиотека в том числе

Comment: Драйвер лежит в папке c:\sqlite\java\connect ?   К проекту библиотека драйвера подключена?

Comment: Драйвер лежит в папке C:/Database/sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1
Библиотека подключена - import java.sql.*;

Comment: я имел ввиду не импорт. не знаю чем у вас собирается проект, для maven это будет выглядеть так : `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.30.1</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Я собираю и запускаю в консоли 
javac Program.java
java Program

Comment: Подсмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661320/how-to-add-native-library-to-java-library-path-with-eclipse-launch-instead-of как при запуске указать какие библиотеки использовать

Comment: Все бралось отсюда - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5UpLpekpdw
Там работаем, а у меня нет

Comment: Смотрите видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnWYNIMTRHY c 9 минуты. Там как раз ваша проблема